# What is the simplest way to use youtube player in nativescript-angular?

Tags: angular, youtube-api, nativescript, youtube-javascript-api, nativescript-angular

[ng2-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-youtube-player) deosn't seem to work in nativescript-angular.

Cant seem to get [this](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer/issues/15) working either.

Does someone have a nativescipt-ized version of ng2-youtube-player?

Answer (score 1):

The `nativescript-videoplayer` works with angular in NativeScript.
The `ng2-youtube-player` is browser based so it won't work with native applications (nativescript, react native, and xamarin like technologies). It would work in a hybrid tech like phonegap with DOM.

Now the part about playing youtube videos without using the native youtube sdks is what you need :) - basically on Android you'll get an error about the video format if you try to drop a youtube url into the native media player on android. What you can do is use this plugin [nativescript-youtube-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-youtube-parser) which according to its readme will get you the actual url needed to work with native mediaplayers. So that is a good option IMO for now.

If you want to read another approach and for more info on videos in nativescript apps - I wrote a blog post over a year ago but still has relevant information.
https://bradmartin.net/2016/01/25/videos-in-a-nativescript-app/

Hope this helps

Comment: the plugin doesn't load a youtube links though ...(?!)